# Examples of Hierarchical-Model-View-Controller (HMVC)?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm interested in the Presentation-Abstraction-Control? (aka Hierarchical-Model-View-Controller (HMVC)) Architectural Pattern for constructing complex user interfaces (GUI or web) and was wondering if anyone was aware of any examples in the wild where I could read the code?

I'm aware of the JavaWorld article and associated letters cited in the [Presentation-Abstraction-Control wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the php world, I'm aware of a few methods that might qualify as HMVC. They all allow calling a controller and displaying the results from within a view. The calls can be nested infinitly creating widgets within widgets.

- Zend Framework: [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)
- CodeIgniter: 3rd party [Modular Extensions - HMVC](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/73177/)
- Kohana: 3rd party [Component](http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=1170) Edit: Kohana 3 now natively supports HMVC

Comment: Yo dawg, we heard you like widgets, so we put a widget inside your widget, so you can call a widget while you're calling a widget.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an HMVC framework a while back for J2EE and FreeMarker:

http://www.neocoders.com/portal/projects/jandal

and recently another one for Javascript:

http://www.neocoders.com/portal/projects/subo

These are fairly 'experimental', but might be of some academic use.

cheers,
Lindsay

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that the Cairngorm framework for Adobe Flex is just one example of an HMVC implementation.  It's open source, so you can find out more information and download the code at [Adobe's website](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm).

Answer (score 1):

The APF-Webframework - http://adventure-php-framework.org/Page/001-Home - uses HMVC since many years, and has a very experienced and engaged developer. Only the small community discourages a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an HMVC framework in PHP called Alloy:

http://alloyframework.org/

It's pretty lightweight and has a modular structure.